# How do Li-Ion batteries detect their temperatures?

Tags: lithium-ion, temperature

I know that Li-Ion batteries have specific charging temperature ranges... but how do they detect when they're too hot/cold to charge and prevent the charger from working?

Secondary question: a component on the board a Li-Ion battery is connected to just blows up. The battery is now always reporting it's too hot, even though I can't feel it rising above room temperature. Why would that component blowing up suddenly make the battery think it's too hot to charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They usually have an internal NTC thermistor, connected between a separate terminal on the battery and battery negative.

If the battery always indicates too hot, the internal thermistor or something in the charger is likely damaged.

The battery itself really doesn't think anything. It only presents a temperature dependent resistance, that the charger will need to measure to decide whether the battery is within its acceptable charging temperature range.

Comment: that makes sense, but why would I start experiencing this problem immediately after a component on the board blew up?

Comment: When the component blew up, it may have opened or shorted a track on the board, fooling the charging circuit into thinking the battery is too hot (or too cold) to charge.

Comment: Note, I experienced a similar problem with 20V LiO battery back for a power tool.  If the battery wasn't fully seated in the charger, it wouldn't charge, because the charger thought is was too hot.

Comment: @PsychonNight depends which component